# python method not being called

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'm writing an automated test using Selenium Python that will play a Web-based game of tic-tac-toe.  The method checkForWinner() needs to check the UI for a line of text displaying the winner after each click, but the method isn't getting called, and I don't know why.

```
    def checkForWinner(self, load_browser):
        
        if Tags.resultOh:
            winner = 'O'
            LOGGER.debug('Winner O')
            assert winner
        elif Tags.resultEx:
            winner = 'X'
            LOGGER.debug('Winner X')
            assert winner
        elif Tags.resultTie:
            winner = 'None'
            LOGGER.debug('Tie')
            assert winner
        else:
            self.test_playGame(load_browser)
```

Whenever the script is run, the game reaches a conclusion and the script hangs.  The browser should close after the game is over, but it doesn't.  It's obviously waiting for a condition that's not being met, but I can't see what it is.

Comment: Is this script being run against another bot?  Or is this bot playing both X and O?

Comment: it's playing against a bot. user always goes first, so this bot makes the first move every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're getting stuck inside your for loop, where you're calling the test_PlayTTT() method recursively.  Since you're playing one bot against another, you need to keep track of the state of the game board after each bot moves.  Right now, it looks like you're only tracking the moves of this bot, but it can potentially click on squares already claimed by the other player.  You want clickedSquares to contain squares clicked by the opposing bot, not just this one.

The maximum number of squares either player can mark is five in a game of tic-tac-toe, so either check for a winner after each player clicks a square, or call checkForWinner() when the size of clickedSquares reaches 5.